# Error: Could not find an installed version of Gradle

Tags: android-studio, cordova, gradle

I am working on an Ionic 5 project. I have installed Android Studio Bumblebee, but when I run `ionic cordova run android`, I get below error. To my understanding, Gradle is automatically installed when I install the Android Studio. Do I need to install Gradle additionally?

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=undefined (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Users\wdwb_\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
in your path, or install Android Studio
```

Comment: I think there's a checkbox which adds gradle to PATH when installing android studio, could be you missed it (also command prompts need to be closed for environment variable changes to activate)

Comment: I had the same error. This helped https://www.andreszsogon.com/upgrading-gradle-version-for-apache-cordova-mobile-apps/

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/guide/platforms/android/index.html). You might need to install Gradle according to your OS.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by installing gradle like this (mac): brew install gradle

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

add `{gradle_path}/bin` to  environment variable on windows.

if you dont have gradle so go to https://gradle.org/install/ Then follow the "Installing manually" section.

Download gradle, which will be in zip file
Create a folder called Gradle
Extract gradle.zip into Gradle folder.
In System variable part, click on 'path' => click 'edit' => then add

```
C:\Gradle\gradle-6.8.3\bin
```